# Is there a quick and easy way to copy an activity?

Tags: activities

We manage activities with many custom fields to record various social parameters of the beneficiaries of our organizations.

These activities are repeated periodically and is common from one activity to another which custom fields change very little.

Is there a quick and easy way to copy an activity? This would save us introduce ever custom fields that are common between two activities.

Note: Events can be copied.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in functionality to copy activities - but my coworker wrote an extension that, amongst other tasks, allows you to copy an activity.  It's organization-specific - for instance, it specifically does NOT copy certain activity fields, and assumes the existence of certain custom fields - but if you've got some developer skills, this is 90% of what you need: https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.multipleactivities/tree/master

Comment: This extension seems a good approximation in the absence of a built-in functionality to copy activities.

Comment: Thanks! I'll also note this was written against CiviCRM 4.4. The existence of the recurring activity engine means there must be a built-in function somewhere in the coffee for copying activities now.

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting you question to mean:

- Contact A might have the same activity type recorded against them in January and March and their custom data will be (mostly) the same each time.
- Contact B might have the same activity type recorded against them in January and March and their custom data will be (mostly) the same each time.
- The custom data for contact A could be quite different from the custom data for Contact B.

I don't think there is an easy way to copy activities.

Events can be copied, but not registrations, contribution pages can be copied but not contributions.

Activities are recorded against contacts as are contributions and registrations and there is no easy copy function.

Answer (score 1):

Are these recurring activities? If so, might want to check the new recurring activity functionality in 4.6 (thx to veda consulting and zing for funding it)